# C++ header file to be included for lexical cast

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, type-conversion, lexical-cast

My compiler(GCC for C++) throws error when I include the #include  header file for converting integer type to string type for some program.
Can anyone help me with this?

This is for a small code in C++, I've tried it for the first time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>// for lexical_cast()
#include <string> // for string

using namespace std;

int main()
{

long long n,i,k;
cin>>n;
ostringstream str1;

str1<<n;

string s = str1.str();
cout<<s<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

No such file or directory.

Comment: You need to actually download boost and point your project (makefile, ...) to this dependency.

Comment: You need to install boost and tell your compiler to use it (read your manuals to learn how). But that code does not need that header, so you can also remove the troublesome line, and installing all of boost just to make that code a little shorter is probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Boost is not part of the standard library, so its implementation does not come with your compiler.

If you wish to use Boost functionality, by including its headers in your source code, you have to actually install Boost so that those headers are available on your development system.

On a system like CentOS, that would come from a package like `boost-devel` (or similar).

However, you're *not* using Boost functionality here, so just remove the include.

Even if you wanted to replace that stringstream usage, we have [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) nowadays.